# Why can't I install this module using npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am very new to Node.JS and have successfully got some packages installed on my Mac. But I am trying to install a module called sbrick-protocol using:

```
npm install sbrick-protocol
```

I get all sorts of weird output that I don't understand:

```
Last login: Wed Jan  1 17:00:38 on ttys000
Gemixin@iMac ~ % npm install sbrick-protocol

> xpc-connection@0.1.4 install /Users/Gemixin/node_modules/xpc-connection
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/src/XpcConnection.o
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:26:77: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'context' was not specified
  target->Set(Nan::New("XpcConnection").ToLocalChecked(), tmpl->GetFunction());
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:6283:3: note: 
      'GetFunction' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Function> GetFunction(
  ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:103:54: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'context' was not specified
    xpcObject = xpc_int64_create(value->IntegerValue());
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:2774:3: note: 
      'IntegerValue' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int64_t> IntegerValue(
  ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:113:49: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'context' was not specified
    Local<Object> valueObject = value->ToObject();
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:2754:3: note: 
      'ToObject' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> ToObject(
  ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:115:78: error: too few arguments to function call,
      expected 2, have 1
    if (valueObject->HasRealNamedProperty(Nan::New("isUuid").ToLocalChecked())) {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                    ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3837:3: note: 
      'HasRealNamedProperty' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> HasRealNamedProperty(Local<Context> context,
  ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:123:49: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'context' was not specified
    Local<Object> valueObject = value->ToObject();
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:2754:3: note: 
      'ToObject' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> ToObject(
  ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:135:40: error: no matching member function for call to
      'GetPropertyNames'
  Local<Array> propertyNames = object->GetPropertyNames();
                               ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3702:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'context', but no
      arguments were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Array> GetPropertyNames(
                                          ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3704:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires at least 4 arguments, but 0 were
      provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Array> GetPropertyNames(
                                          ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:138:48: error: no matching member function for call to
      'Get'
    Local<Value> propertyName = propertyNames->Get(i);
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:143:88: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'context' was not specified
  ...propertyValue = object->GetRealNamedProperty(propertyName->ToString());
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:2750:3: note: 
      'ToString' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ToString(
  ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:160:33: error: no matching member function for call to
      'Get'
    Local<Value> value = array->Get(i);
                         ~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:200:13: error: no matching member function for call to
      'Set'
    object->Set(Nan::New<String>(key).ToLocalChecked(), XpcConnection::X...
    ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:212:12: error: no matching member function for call to
      'Set'
    array->Set(Nan::New<Number>(index), XpcConnection::XpcObjectToValue(value));
    ~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:254:12: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::New<Object>(this->This), Nan::New("emit").T...
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:1045:3: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked
      deprecated here
  NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
  ^
../../nan/nan.h:104:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
# define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                       ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:263:12: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::New<Object>(this->This), Nan::New("emit").T...
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:1045:3: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked
      deprecated here
  NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
  ^
../../nan/nan.h:104:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
# define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                       ^
2 warnings and 11 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/XpcConnection.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/Gemixin/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:305:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/Gemixin/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/bin/node" "/Users/Gemixin/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Gemixin/node_modules/xpc-connection
gyp ERR! node -v v13.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN gemixin@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN gemixin@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bluetooth-hci-socket@0.5.1 (node_modules/bluetooth-hci-socket):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for bluetooth-hci-socket@0.5.1: wanted {"os":"linux,android,win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: xpc-connection@0.1.4 (node_modules/xpc-connection):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: xpc-connection@0.1.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ sbrick-protocol@3.0.0
updated 1 package and audited 464 packages in 6.624s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I tried running the commands as suggested:

```
Gemixin@iMac ~ % npm fund
gemixin@1.0.0
└─┬ glob@7.1.6
  └── url: https://github.com/sponsors/isaacs
```

Then:

```
npm audit fix
```

But that just printed out a similar ouput to the original install command, ending with:

```
fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 464 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated
```

The folder "sbrick-protocol" has been created in my modules folder so I thought I'd try and run a simple JS program using it, but I get told it's missing module 'xpc-connection'. So I try and run `npm install xpc-connection` and I get a similar output to before:

```
Gemixin@iMac ~ % npm install xpc-connection

> xpc-connection@0.1.4 install /Users/Gemixin/node_modules/xpc-connection
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/src/XpcConnection.o
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:26:77: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'context' was not specified
  target->Set(Nan::New("XpcConnection").ToLocalChecked(), tmpl->GetFunction());
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:6283:3: note: 
      'GetFunction' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Function> GetFunction(
  ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:103:54: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'context' was not specified
    xpcObject = xpc_int64_create(value->IntegerValue());
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:2774:3: note: 
      'IntegerValue' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int64_t> IntegerValue(
  ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:113:49: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'context' was not specified
    Local<Object> valueObject = value->ToObject();
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:2754:3: note: 
      'ToObject' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> ToObject(
  ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:115:78: error: too few arguments to function call,
      expected 2, have 1
    if (valueObject->HasRealNamedProperty(Nan::New("isUuid").ToLocalChecked())) {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                    ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3837:3: note: 
      'HasRealNamedProperty' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> HasRealNamedProperty(Local<Context> context,
  ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:123:49: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'context' was not specified
    Local<Object> valueObject = value->ToObject();
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:2754:3: note: 
      'ToObject' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> ToObject(
  ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:135:40: error: no matching member function for call to
      'GetPropertyNames'
  Local<Array> propertyNames = object->GetPropertyNames();
                               ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3702:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'context', but no
      arguments were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Array> GetPropertyNames(
                                          ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3704:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires at least 4 arguments, but 0 were
      provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Array> GetPropertyNames(
                                          ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:138:48: error: no matching member function for call to
      'Get'
    Local<Value> propertyName = propertyNames->Get(i);
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:143:88: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'context' was not specified
  ...propertyValue = object->GetRealNamedProperty(propertyName->ToString());
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:2750:3: note: 
      'ToString' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ToString(
  ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:160:33: error: no matching member function for call to
      'Get'
    Local<Value> value = array->Get(i);
                         ~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:200:13: error: no matching member function for call to
      'Set'
    object->Set(Nan::New<String>(key).ToLocalChecked(), XpcConnection::X...
    ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:212:12: error: no matching member function for call to
      'Set'
    array->Set(Nan::New<Number>(index), XpcConnection::XpcObjectToValue(value));
    ~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/Gemixin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:254:12: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::New<Object>(this->This), Nan::New("emit").T...
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:1045:3: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked
      deprecated here
  NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
  ^
../../nan/nan.h:104:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
# define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                       ^
../src/XpcConnection.cpp:263:12: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::New<Object>(this->This), Nan::New("emit").T...
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:1045:3: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked
      deprecated here
  NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
  ^
../../nan/nan.h:104:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
# define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                       ^
2 warnings and 11 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/XpcConnection.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/Gemixin/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:305:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/Gemixin/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/bin/node" "/Users/Gemixin/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Gemixin/node_modules/xpc-connection
gyp ERR! node -v v13.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN gemixin@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN gemixin@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bluetooth-hci-socket@0.5.1 (node_modules/bluetooth-hci-socket):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for bluetooth-hci-socket@0.5.1: wanted {"os":"linux,android,win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! xpc-connection@0.1.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the xpc-connection@0.1.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Gemixin/.npm/_logs/2020-01-01T17_40_53_996Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you include your .txt files on the question..

Comment: So, the library apparently has some native add-on code in it that `install` is trying to compile.  And, it's getting lots of warnings/errors which I would guess means that it's written for an older version of node.js than you are using.  It ends witha  build error so the desired target is not properly created.  I'd suggest doing some searching on node version compatibility for that library.  Or contact the author and ask.

Comment: In looking at the github repository, it does not look like it's been meaningfully updated in 3 years.

Comment: Sorry the links to code output were wrong initially but now fixed. I am getting that same output no matter what I try and install with npm now. Just tried uuid as an example having successfully installed that module before and I get the same output starting with:
> xpc-connection@0.1.4 install /Users/Gemixin/node_modules/xpc-connection
> node-gyp rebuild

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, the library apparently has some native add-on code in it that `install` is trying to compile. And, it's getting lots of warnings/errors which I would guess means that it's written for an older version of node.js than you are using. It ends with a build error so the desired target is not properly created. I'd suggest doing some searching on node version compatibility for that library. Or contact the author and ask.

In looking at the github repository, it does not look like it's been meaningfully updated in 3 years so you may have to try an older version of node.js or find a different library.

Note: You may want to think twice about basing a project on an unmaintained library (particularly one that's an add-on and uses native code) unless you plan on maintaining it yourself so it can work with future versions of node.js.

Answer (score 6):

I downgraded Node.JS to version 8.15.1 and it worked.

Comment: for stackoverflow stats, please check your answer as accepted